# Do I have to make another text file before executing this program?

Tags: python, bash

I am in Exercise 15 chapter from the book Learn the python the hard way.
As the book suggest to run the command on bash "python ex15.py ex15_sample.txt" I just followed this command.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

However the error is appeared like this on bash.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex15.py", line 5, in <module>
    txt = open(filename)
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'ex15_sample.txt'
```

I made a file by using 'mkdir ex15_sample.txt' and even tried to literal text file on the same directory but the error is still appeared.

Comment: You use `touch` if you're on bash -> `touch ex15_sample.txt`. `mkdir` creates an empty directory.

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. Also be aware that Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so you really ought to be learning Python 3, unless you need Python 2 to work on legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `man mkdir` on shell and the first thing you'll see is this:

```
NAME
     mkdir -- make directories
```

As the name suggests, `mkdir` is used for creating *directories*. In this case, an empty directory called `ex15_sample.txt` is created, so `open` throws the error you see.

If you want to create a file, use `touch`:

```
touch ex15_sample.txt
```

`touch` updates the `mtime` of a file if it exists, or creates the file if it does not.

Alternatively, use `cat` with `>`:

```
cat > ex15_sample.txt
```

After running the first command, hit `Ctrl+C`, to create an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a directory with mkdir.

To create a text file type in terminal, in the same directory your python file:

```
nano ex15_sample.txt
```

This will let you to a text editor, just type your text and save pressing `crtl+x` and confirming pressing `y` and `enter`

Now you are be able to open the file.